# Data is not fetching, return 0

Tags: database

Data is not fetching get customer id null.?
Please review my code.
Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Collect grand total address amount
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 * @return $this
 */
protected $quoteValidator = null;

protected $rewardspointCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\CollectionFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory
        ) {
    $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory = $rewardspointCollectionFactory;
}

public function collect(
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


    $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
    $fee = 10; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
    $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

    $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

    $total->setFee($balance);
    $total->setBaseFee($balance);

    $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
    $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


    return $this;
}

protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total) {
    $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
    $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return array|null
 */

/**
 * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {



    $rewardspointCollection = $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory->create();
    $customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();

    $rewardspointCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('dukaaniatest_id',$customerId);
    if(count($rewardspointCollection) > 0){
       $firstItem =  $rewardspointCollection->geFirstItem();

       return [
        'code' => 'fee',
        'title' => $firstItem->getData('title'),
        'value' => $firstItem->getData('author')
    ];
    }else{
        return [
        'code' => 'fee',
        'title' => 'Fee',
        'value' => '0',
    ];
    }



}

/**
 * Get Subtotal label
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getLabel() {
    return __('Fee');
}
```

}

Comment: You want to get customer id from order data or ?

Comment: I want to fetch data from a custom table that i  integrated from model, controller,
just echo the data that i fetched

Comment: Please check $customerId what is return after sign in and without sign in.

Comment: without sign in return 0

Comment: Okay. Then, it will return blank data if customer not logged in or it will return data if that customer id record exist in your custom table.

Comment: so can you modify my code that without sign in it return something

Comment: after sign in also it returns 0 blank

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83929/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jhon-jhon-doe).

Comment: please check chatbox